# push two arrays as json objects with our own keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have to arrays like these:

```
var a1= ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
var a2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

ANd I want to format them into an array of objects like this:

```
js = [
    {key = "a", val=1}
    {key = "b", val=2}
    {key = "c", val=3}
    {key = "d", val=4}
    {key = "e", val=5}
    {key = "f", val=6}
]
```

I tried something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        var obj = {};
        if (i == j) {
            obj.key = a1[i];
            obj.value = a2[j];
            js.push(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not able to get the desired output. Can anyone help me?

Comment: { key=a, val=1}, you sure? That's not desired output / valid object. You may need {key: "a", val: 1} as a desired output instead! And if so, there are good answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both arrays always have the same length, you can combine them using `Array#map`:

```js
function arraysToObject(keyArr, valArr) {
  if(keyArr.length !== valArr.length) throw "Arrays must be of same length";
  else return keyArr.map((e,i) => {
    return {key:e, val:valArr[i]};
  });
}

let a1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
let a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

let a3 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
let a4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log(JSON.stringify(arraysToObject(a1, a2))); // runs fine
console.log(arraysToObject(a3, a4)); // throws an error
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice solution, only thing missing is checking 'i' < a2.length

Comment: That's better, perfect, although, not quite, change the order around in the if, a2[I] could still error, in fact a2[I] isn't required at all.

Comment: @SPlatten Personally I think the checking here in a Snippet, distracts away from the solution.  But if your are going to do validation, this would be the wrong way anyway.  The function does not fail on invalid data, it would be much better to throw an exception.

Comment: It now throws an exception if a2 doesn't have enough elements

Answer (score 2):

If you like to do it using ES6, it is a one-liner using `Array#map`:

```js
var a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
var a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

var res = a1.map((key, index) => ({key, val: a2[index]}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need one loop, since `a1` and `a2` have the same length. Try like:

```
var js= [];
for(var i=0; i<a1.length;i++){ 
    var obj = {};
    obj.key = a1[i];
    obj.value = a2[i];
    js.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Add a bit of validation to ensure that 'i' is valid for a2, as it assumes that a1 and a2 will be the same size.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const a1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
      a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
      
let result = a1.reduce((r,v,i) => r.concat({key:v,val:a2[i]}), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

> **Using [Destructuring_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**

```js
const a1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
      a2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
      
let result = a1.reduce((r,v,i) => [...r,{key:v,val:a2[i]}], []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a1= ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
var a2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

var js = a1.map( ( key, index ) => { 
  
  return ( {
    key : key,
    value : a2[index],
  } );
  
} );

console.log(JSON.stringify(js))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to aggregate the desired output:

```
var a1= ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
var a2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var js = a1.map((k, i) => ({key: k, val: a2[i]}));

console.log(js);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired result